# Specific Trapezoidal Wave Formula

Tags: graphing-functions

I have a wave that I've never seeen like below:

[Here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xVyw.png)

I should find its formula to calculate something. I'd like to ask whether this wave has a formula or I should find it. I researchet it by chopped triangular waves keyword and another but there was no excatly same graphs. Just there was a chopped sinus graph.

I tried to find it and it is like below:

[Here the formula I found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCkT9.jpg)

When I draw this formula by matlab, unfortunately I don't get the right wave shape. Could you mark where is wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, but it is almost impossible to read your text...

Comment: @JeanMarie Sometimes I can't read... I will try to edit and let you know.

Comment: @JeanMarie I edited the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with expression

$$A(1-\tfrac{u}{2t})$$

Indeed, placing $t$ in the denominator gives you a piece of hyperbola instead of a straight line...

---

**Edit 1:** Here is a Matlab program based on a completely different point of view, with convolution:

```
clear all;close all;hold on;
axis([0,1500,-250,250]);
rec=@(t,u)(heaviside(u/2-t).*heaviside(u/2+t));% rect function
t=-pi/2:0.01:pi/2;
f=conv(rec(t,0.1),rec(t,1),'same');% conv. of two rect = trapezoid
Z=zeros(1,100);
np=10;%number of periods
g=repmat([1,Z,-1,Z],[1,np]);% Dirac comb with alternate peaks giving the periodization:
h=conv(g,f,'same');plot(h,'r');
```

---

**Edit 2:** A very astute compact way to obtain a periodic trapezoidal wave [on this site](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/684163-generating-periodic-trapezoidal-waves-with-ramps):

> ```
> a = 10  % Amplitude
> m = 5   % Time Period
> l = 5   % Horizontal Spread
> c = 2   % Vertical Spread
> x = 0:.1:50 %Sample Points
> TW = (a/pi)*(asin(sin((pi/m)*x+l))+acos(cos((pi/m)*x+l)))-a/2+c;
> plot(x,TW)
> ```

**Edit 3:**

The Fourier series of this odd function has only $b_n$ coefficients:

$$f(t)=\frac{8A}{\pi u}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sin ( { (2n-1) u/2 }) \over (2n-1)^2} \cdot \sin((2n-1) t)$$

[A reference for this](https://developpaper.com/fourier-series-expansion-of-common-waveforms/)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to find right equation until you provide me.

Comment: I just added a Matlab program completely based on convolution in order to enrich the approach.

Comment: I just added a second edit.

Comment: I checked your answer. Thank you for your effort. Both are useful methods,I will vote for them. But I need a linear equation. Because I have to calculate its fourier series and I am sure of that I can't integrate both of them. If you can provide me a linear equation, I would be pleasure. If you can't, not problem because you helped me to see the wrong in my equation. I am trying to fix it. I guess I can't vote because of my less reputation.

Comment: 1) In fact, the Fourier series of a trapezoidal wave is known (I will give you an indication as "edit 3") 2) of course you can vote (select the green "check" sign).

Comment: Thank you so much again. Actually, I will use this wave for my homework and I am not sure of that our teacher will accept my answer without my way. Also I compose the equation as linear form. I can share it at here if it is useful.